# How to make 301 redirect in NextJS Vercel project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, vercel

How can I make 301 re directions from one url to another in NextJS application that is stored on Vercel?

I tried to add custom express server using server.js file but the re directions works only locally and then I read this at vercel:
"A custom server can not be deployed on Vercel, the platform Next.js was made for."
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

Is there any way to make 301 re directions and still host my app on Vercel?

Answer (score 2):

If you're hosting on Vercel with NextJS and have a `next.config.js` and not a `vercel.json` you can do the following;

Edit `next.config.js`:

```js
const moduleExports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/foo',
        destination: '/bar'
      }
    ]
  }
};


module.exports = moduleExports;
```

Why does this work?:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can configure redirects within Vercel (while keeping the project hosted on Vercel). You just have to use a vercel.json file in the root of your directory. The format of the redirect is like this:

```
// vercel.json
{
  "source": "/when-user-hits-this-path",
  "destination": "/redirect-them-to-this-path"
}
```

There's more information on specifics in the vercel docs: https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/redirects

Good luck!

- Jake

Comment: Note that this method will not work at runtime. This will not work for a use case such as checking a CMS or database if the redirect should take place.